# templated operator for strongly typed enumerations

Tags: c++, enums, operator-overloading

I have two enumerations with underlying type `uint32_t`. and I need constexpr OR operator for them because some of members should consist with result of OR of other members. I wanted to avoid to implement the operator twice or more times.

So, I tried to use template to achieve it.

```
    template <enum class E>
    constexpr uint32_t operator|(const E&   left, const E& right)
    {
        return (uint32_t)left | (uint32_t)right;
    }

    template <enum class E>
    constexpr uint32_t operator|(const uint32_t& left, const E& right)
    {
        return left | (uint32_t)right;
    }

    enum class U32Enum1 : uint32_t { 
        OtherMember1 = 0x01L,
        OtherMember2 = 0x02L,
        SomeOfMember = OtherMember1 | OtherMember2 // Not work
    }

    enum class U32Enum2 : uint32_t {
        OtherMember1 = 0x01L,
        OtherMember2 = 0x02L,
        SomeOfMember = OtherMember1 | OtherMember2 // Not work    
    }
```

However, It won't work and compiler gave me a message that no matching operands for operator `|`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the error message

Comment: cant you cast to the underlying type and then simply use the existing `operator|` for `uint32_t` ?

Comment: @user463035818 There are only two members are described on example, but more members are involved in this situation. I could cast each of them into underlying types, however It messes code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`template <enum class E>` is not the good syntax, you might do instead:

```
template <class E, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<E>::value, int> = 0>
constexpr E operator|(const E&   left, const E& right)
{
    return static_cast<E>((uint32_t)left | (uint32_t)right);
}
```

and using underlying type is even better:

```
template <class E, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<E>::value, int> = 0>
constexpr E operator|(const E&   left, const E& right)
{
    using T = typename std::underlying_type<E>::type;
    return static_cast<E>(static_cast<T>(left) | static_cast<T>(right));
}
```

Comment: `template <enum class E>` expects a enum value of type `E`, not a type? I am a bit confused by that syntax

Comment: @user463035818: I got warning for `template <enum class E>` (*"elaborated-type-specifier for a scoped enum must not use the 'class' keyword"*), so in fact `template <enum class E>` is `template <enum E /*e*/>` or even `template <E /*e*/>`.

Comment: I tried your solution, but still same error messages shown, E3049, `no operator "|" matches these operands`

Comment: Oh, I got some mistypes. as I revise it, The problem is gone! Thank you for helping!